# Dynamic Models Django 2019

Tags: python, django, django-models

Okay, I know there are threads all over the place from outdated ways to make **dynamic django models** meaning, they are altered by a user at runtime of the application. I am not finding a solid solution outside of using custom SQL to make dynamic tables in my project, so I am hoping there is a way to dynamically create a model during runtime, so it can be used in Django's ORM.

**So far in the last few weeks of checking, this seems either overly complicated or impossible for my situation**

For example and in brevity, I have a `unit_declaration` model, which holds column names for each `Property` a client 'owns'. I then take those `column names` and currently create a custom SQL query to build a `unit` table based on those columns for each `property` (i.e. **_[PROPERTYID]_units**). I want to be able to **not** use custom SQL to generate the creation of client `property-unit` tables at runtime, how is this possible (and I need a real example because nothing is making sense to me elsewhere)?

I can certainly provide code as to what I am doing so far, and I completely unvderstand this is the point of SO, but I am hitting a block and need a suggestion and believe a random post of code is unhelpful as it shows only what I have described. I learned today that Django's Foreign Keys are very convenient, and I cannot use them with customly declared SQL tables (outside of Django's ORM), how do I make a runtime-based model?

I have looked at the PyPi package of `django-dynamic-models`, but it seems outdated as the latest release was 2014. Is there a better option or would you suggest I stick with custom SQL queries to make my dynamic tables for my project?

Comment: Instead of using dynamic models, have you considered using a separate model?  I.e. `PropertyUnit` and `PropertyUnitValue` models?

Comment: @A. J. Parr Yes, I have thought that through. The issue is each `Property` can have `Units` that have different columns. (for example, 1 property could track floor number for units, another could track parking spot numbers for its units) I could store the unit-submission in a `PropertyUnit` table as a string `dict()`, but that could be a large submission, which makes parsing the data rather complicated/unnecessary for thousands of entered units.

Comment: @ViaTech: Have you found a good solution to this problem? I need to implement roughly the same logic. I need to create a unit table (according to a table template) for each unit in unit_declaration for each user.

Comment: @Ecuashungo at this moment no, true dynamic runtime models, outside of pure SQL seem to still be infeasible. I have compromised with functionality and used JSONFields so I still have the power of Django's ORM, but that is not the ideal case.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Postgresql, the best solution may just be adding a [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield). It can be queried within the ORM, and can add a ton of flexibility without requiring new tables or a huge amount of custom code for dynamic models.

Here are a [couple](https://riptutorial.com/django/topic/1759/jsonfield---a-postgresql-specific-field) [examples](http://orokusaki.posthaven.com/djangos-new-jsonfield-is-awesome) of its use.

Update: With modern versions of django you can use JSONField with the majority of its benefits regardless of that database backend you use!

Comment: I actually do this for a different feature of the project, but it is not viable for `Units`. For example, I need my clients to be able to edit the column names (or if we are talking about objects; property names) of thier `Units`, but at the same time I **always** need these column/property names to be universally bound to each `Unit`at a `Property` for reporting purposes. I can't load a table of data with the correct headers if the keys in a saved `dict()` are changed for various units. I need a way to implement real Dynamic Django Models